# Is it possible to set the css position property independantly for vertical and horizontal axes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I wanted an element to be positioned vertically absolutely, but horizontally relative. Is this possible with css/html/javascript?

Comment: How about explaining what you're trying to achieve rather than what have asked so far? Also, I don't think setting position for one axis only makes much sense and as such, pretty sure it cannot be done.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do with your code, you may want to use [flex positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp). However, more information on what you're trying to accomplish would make it easier to help you out.

Comment: I had a problem to which this was a considered solution, but I figured out a better way to do it. However, I was still curious if this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which case could be fine to use this mix, but it is possible,
if you only define `top`/`bottom` properties in a `position:absolute` element.

The left/right position of the element will be "relative" if you leave it untouched.

In the following example, the second container has a mixed positioning.

```css
.example{
   margin: 30px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.item1, .item2{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
}

#example2 .item2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="example">
   <div class="item1">Item1</div>
   <div class="item2">Item2</div>
</div>

<div id="example2" class="example">
   <div class="item1">Item1</div>
   <div class="item2">Item2</div>
</div>
```